# why is Linux a base for Android devices

Tags: android

I have 2 questions:

1. Why did the Android founders choose Linux?
2. Is Linux the so called middleware in Android?

Comment: Middleware between what and what?

Answer (score 7):

This seems to hold the answer:
http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Android_FAQ#Q:_Why_does_Android_use_the_a_GPL_Linux_kernel.2C_but_libraries_and_user_space_apps_that_are_licensed_more_liberal_open_source.2Ffree_software_licenses.3F

Q: Why does Android use the a GPL Linux kernel, but libraries and user space apps that are licensed more liberal open source/free software licenses?

A: To put it simply - the Linux kernel has wide hardware and industry support, and keeping GPL code in the kernel as much as possible makes a pretty clear line between GPLed stuff and unencumbered stuff, but vendors are somewhat scared of the GPL, so it is avoided as much as possible outside the kernel. It seems that currently bluez is about the only userspace code in android which is GPLed. Official reasons for why to use a Linux kernel from a Google IO preso:

- Great memory and process management
- Permissions-based security model
- Proven driver model
- Support for shared libraries
- Itʼs already open source!

For an unofficial explanation of why Google prefers the Apache2 license over the GPL license, please see this ArsTechnica article: http://arstechnica.com/news.ars/post/20071106-why-google-chose-the-apache-software-license-over-gplv2.html

Answer (score 2):

1. I'm not sure it's possible to give an absolute answer, but the main reason for choosing Linux is probably that it's free and widely supported. Also, there's a very strong Linux community (thus a lot of know-how).
2. Linux is an operating system kernel, not middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Linux was chosen because it's open and customizable enough to suit Android's needs.

Writing an entire OS is time-intensive and expensive.

Answer (score 0):

1. Linux is open source. Android needed to be.
2. Android uses a Linux kernel. Check out this video and the two others in the series describing Android in more detail: http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=QBGfUs9mQYY