# Why only Linux Kernel is used for android and no other kernel?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel

Just faced an interview on android and came home and there was only one question which I was not confident about. The interviewer asked me that why only Linux kernel is used for the integration between h/w and s/w in android and why no other kernel. I was blank, to be frank but I said they both are open sources, he looked at me and smiled. I want to know the real answer.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5393296/418609).

Comment: *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.* — http://stackoverflow.com/faq  (and "Why has nobody done the work to make X happen?" is an open-ended question)

Comment: @Quentin You can flag questions you know.

Comment: @adrianp — And I can explain why too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Linux is open source" that means, one can make enhancements upon the Linux kernel structure( maintaining the GNU licence agreement). Hence, Android takes Linux 2.6 as its underlying kernel and makes enhancements to meet mobile O/S requirements such as better memory management, better processor management.

Comment: That explains (sort of) "Why Linux", but it doesn't answer the question, which is "Why *only* Linux". There are other open source kernels out there.

Comment: because Linux is highly customizable and Linux is not only for desktops but also for mobility devices. Can u name any other O/S which has this much variety?

Comment: Symbian, OS X, Windows, and various BSDs spring to mind.

Comment: All those you said use Linux directly or in a hybrid environment. Please Google and then post!

Comment: None of them are Linux based.

Comment: all are hybrid.. kindly follow the comment...

Comment: In what way, precisely, does Symbian make use of code written for the Linux kernel?

Comment: @ParijatBose So you are saying that the mobile versions of Windows "use Linux directly or in a hybrid environment"?

Comment: @quentin- nope, that wud then mean that symbian is also open source. But that isnt. This is being deviated from the topic. Kindly stick to it. Linux is for every system as because it is customizable and others are having two versions, for desktop and mobile.

Comment: @ParijatBose — Are you retracting your earlier statement "All those you said use Linux directly or in a hybrid environment" then?

Comment: @ParijatBose — All of the examples I listed (with the possible, but improbable, exception of Windows) which have desktop and mobile variants, either build the mobile and desktop variants from the same source tree or share code between them. (Much like Android does).

Comment: Earlier versions of the OS X kernel [were open source](http://slashdot.org/story/06/05/17/1453206/mac-os-x-kernel-source-now-closed), [ditto Symbian](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Nokia-confirms-Symbian-no-longer-open-source-1222637.html) (old open source licenses for them will still be valid), several BSD based kernels *are* open source.

Comment: Maybe Google might have started from here. Like which all the opensource posix compliant OS are there. Which one is best/comparison(preemptive, scalability-from server to desktop to small mmu less micro controller, stable).Number of active developers for the OS. How frequent are the OS updates. So that makes me decide to go for Linux. @Parijat: no offense I would like to update that they have now moved to 3+ kernel versions. not sure, they are working on 3.5+ kernel currently.